# Jupyter Error: Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got Series)

Tags: python, jupyter, spacy

Argument 'string' has incorrect type (expected str, got Series)

Hello,
Creating a list from a dataframe and trying to perform nlp against it.

```
list_rt=df['ReportText']
doc = nlp(list_rt)
visualize_ent(list_rt)
```

Comment: Right, `list_rt` is a series. You need ot use something like `list_rt = df['ReportText'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what ended up working for me:

```
list_rt = df['ReportText']
for i in list_rt:
    doc=nlp(i)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        visualize_ent(doc)
```